# an acronym (NOTOP)

Tags: terminology, first-order-logic, model-theory

What does the acronym NOTOP [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9910158.pdf) on the page $26$ stand for and how is it defined?

Comment: A cursory search leads me to DOP = dimensional order property, OTOP = omitting types order property.  The negations of these properties are NDOP and NOTOP respectively.  I found these in [this search](https://books.google.com/books?id=7vBKDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140&dq=ndop+math&source=bl&ots=QA7niOmyOt&sig=ACfU3U0EU3VW99ZG0RuK_0iGVZTGaJFspA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjd2om6_fzpAhViRDABHcmZAgkQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=ndop%20math&f=false).  Unfortunately I can't tell you the meanings of these further as I don't have a copy of the book and the page on which they are defined aren't in the preview.

Comment: Still, someone with more experience with Model Theory or access to the book should be able to help further.  Otherwise, at least giving you the words for the acronym may be enough to lead you to find a definition yourself in one of your sources.

Comment: The OTOP is defined [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.ndjfl/1039700699) [PDF], and the DOP is **Definition 2.1** of [this PDF](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.07034.pdf).